# Crash when invoking Promise::Defered.Resolve() in AsyncWork.OnOK function

Tags: node.js, node-addon-api

I pass a `Napi::Promise::Deferred` to a AsyncWorker, and call `Promise::Defered.Resolve()` in AynscWork.OnOK. but it always crash when I call Resolve()

```cpp
// node addon function 

Napi::Promise FileMd5Async(const Napi::CallbackInfo& info) {
    Napi::Env env = info.Env();
    auto filePath = info[0].As<Napi::String>().Utf8Value();
    Napi::Promise::Deferred deferred = Napi::Promise::Deferred::New(env);
    HashAsyncWorker *hashAsyncWorker = new HashAsyncWorker(env, deferred, filePath);
    hashAsyncWorker->Queue();
    return deferred.Promise();
}

// HashAsyncWorker.h
#pragma once
#include "third_party/node-addon-api/napi.h"

class HashAsyncWorker : public Napi::AsyncWorker {
    
    public:
        HashAsyncWorker(Napi::Env &env, Napi::Promise::Deferred& deferred, std::string filePath);
        ~HashAsyncWorker() override {};

        void Execute() override;
        void OnOK() override;
        void OnError(Napi::Error const &error) override;

    private:
        Napi::Env &env;
        Napi::Promise::Deferred& deferred;
        std::string filePath;
        std::string hashResult;
};

// // HashAsyncWorker.cc
#include "HashAsyncWorker.H"
#include "hash_utils.h"

HashAsyncWorker::HashAsyncWorker(Napi::Env &env, Napi::Promise::Deferred& deferred, std::string filePath) : Napi::AsyncWorker(env), env(env), deferred(deferred), filePath(filePath), hashResult("") {

}

void HashAsyncWorker::Execute() {
    hashResult = hash_utils::FileMd5(filePath);
}

void HashAsyncWorker::OnOK() {
    // crash here  
    //[1]    37056 segmentation fault  
    deferred.Resolve(Napi::String::New(Env(), hashResult)); 
}

void HashAsyncWorker::OnError(Napi::Error const &error) {
    deferred.Reject(error.Value());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right. It crashes because created on the heap and used further by node-addon-api `HashAsyncWorker` outlives the `Deferred` object created on the stack of `FileMd5Async` function.

To prevent crashing you need to make sure `deferred` lives long enough for `onOK` function to access a valid value.

In fact, N-API objects, like `napi_value`, `napi_deferred`, etc. (of which node-addon-api is a thin wrapper) are pointers, meaning that they can be freely copied.

This way, if you just remove the references that you use to pass `deferred` around, you will prevent crashing from happening.

Removal of three ampersands in the constructor declaration, implementation and field declaration should be enough:

```cpp
// HashAsyncWorker.h
#pragma once
#include "third_party/node-addon-api/napi.h"

class HashAsyncWorker : public Napi::AsyncWorker {
    
    public:
        HashAsyncWorker(Napi::Env &env, Napi::Promise::Deferred deferred, std::string filePath);
        ~HashAsyncWorker() override {};

        void Execute() override;
        void OnOK() override;
        void OnError(Napi::Error const &error) override;

    private:
        Napi::Env &env;
        Napi::Promise::Deferred deferred;
        std::string filePath;
        std::string hashResult;
};

// // HashAsyncWorker.cc
#include "HashAsyncWorker.H"
#include "hash_utils.h"

HashAsyncWorker::HashAsyncWorker(Napi::Env &env, Napi::Promise::Deferred deferred, std::string filePath) : Napi::AsyncWorker(env), env(env), deferred(deferred), filePath(filePath), hashResult("") {

}
```